# How do I bind to property within ancestor's data context?

Tags: wpf, binding, itemscontrol, relativesource

I have an ItemsControl defined as shown below.  Basically, I have a list of editors (EditorList) and I want hyperlinks for each.  However, my open command (OpenEditorCommand) property is at the same level as the list of editors.  How do I refer to that property when the context is set to the item within the list.  I've tried working with the RelativeSource method but it's too convoluted for me to understand.  Am I on the right track?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EditorList}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Margin="2,6" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Hyperlink Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl, AncestorLevel=2, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=OpenEditorCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Name}">
               <StackPanel>
                  <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Width=32/>
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
               </StackPanel>
            </Hyperlink>
         </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Either the website isn't working or my browser needs to be updated because I'm not seeing the code formatting button.  Let me try on a different computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need to set the `AncestorLevel` in cases where there is possibly more than one ancestor of the searched type existing in the element tree. The default value is 1 which mean find the closest.

But you need to specify in the `Path` that you want to bind to the `OpenEditorCommand` on the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl`:

```
Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.OpenEditorCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
```

Comment: That did the trick...forgot the "DataContext." in the Path.  Thanks.